# Shift values in columns up if there are missing values above

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
             var1 = c("100", "200", "300", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                      "100", "200", "300", NA, NA, NA), 
             var2 = c("100", NA, NA, "400", "500", "600", NA, NA,
                      NA, NA, NA, "400", NA, NA),
             var3 = c("200", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "700", "800",
                      "500", NA, NA, NA, "500", "600"))
```

which looks like this:

```
  id var1 var2 var3
   A  100  100  200
   A  200 <NA> <NA>
   A  300 <NA> <NA>
   A <NA>  400 <NA>
   A <NA>  500 <NA>
   A <NA>  600 <NA>
   A <NA> <NA>  700
   A <NA> <NA>  800
   B  100 <NA>  500
   B  200 <NA> <NA>
   B  300 <NA> <NA>
   B <NA>  400 <NA>
   B <NA> <NA>  500
   B <NA> <NA>  600
```

I would like to shift values in columns up if there are missing values above (by group). The result should look like this:

```
  id var1 var2 var3
   A  100  100  200
   A  200  400  700
   A  300  500  800
   A <NA>  600 <NA>
   B  100  400  500
   B  200 <NA>  500
   B  300 <NA>  600
```

I have no idea how to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Should "NA" be NA (i.e not a string?)

Comment: Edit your question. NA is currently a string.

Comment: Are your numbers really of class `character`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a rough concept using `data.table` that can be refined:

```
library(data.table)
# Helper function:
shift_up <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  length(x) <- n
  x
}

setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, shift_up), id][!(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3))]

   id var1 var2 var3
1:  A  100  100  200
2:  A  200  400  700
3:  A  300  500  800
4:  A <NA>  600 <NA>
5:  B  100  400  500
6:  B  200 <NA>  500
7:  B  300 <NA>  600
```

Comment: Hi snoram! Thanks for helping me with this! Your codes work out well! I just want to know if there is a simple way to write "[!(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3))]". In my actual data frame, I have over 30 variables. It would be great if I don't have to write this one by one. Thanks again!

Comment: In the last step, specify the `.SDcols` and you can use `!Reduce('&', .SD)` to create the logical vector

Comment: Also if it is all the columns except the `id` you could do smth like: `out <- df[, lapply(.SD, shift_up), id]; out[rowSums(is.na(out[,!"id"])) < (length(out) - 1)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think this is the most efficient way to do it but one option

```
library(rowr)

df1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) {
    data.frame(id = x$id[1], do.call(cbind.fill,c(sapply(x[-1], na.omit),fill = NA)))
}))
names(df1) <- names(df)
df1


#    id   var1   var2   var3
#A.1  A    100    100    200
#A.2  A    200    400    700
#A.3  A    300    500    800
#A.4  A   <NA>    600   <NA>
#B.1  B    100    400    500
#B.2  B    200   <NA>    500
#B.3  B    300   <NA>    600
```

We `split` the dataframe into list of dataframe for every `id` and for each dataframe we remove the `NA` values using `na.omit` and use `cbind.fill` to fill the values with `NA` and finally merge the list of dataframes back into one using `rbind` with `do.call`.

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks for the excellent code! Just wondering if there is a way to keep the column names unchanged? In my actual data frame, the columns names are years; it will be very confusing if I mess it up. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Ruilin yes, you can save the output into different object and rename it using the original dataframe.  Updated the answer with that change.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id', `order` the other column based on the NA values, then create an index to remove the rows where all the elements are `NA`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df)[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]), id]
df1[df1[,!Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na)), .SDcols = var1:var3]]
#   id var1 var2 var3
#1:  A  100  100  200
#2:  A  200  400  700
#3:  A  300  500  800
#4:  A <NA>  600 <NA>
#5:  B  100  400  500
#6:  B  200 <NA>  500
#7:  B  300 <NA>  600
```

---

Or using the same logic with `tidyverse`.  Grouped by 'id', change the `order` or elements in all other column with `mutate_all` by  `order`ing on the logical vector (`is.na(column)`) and keep the rows having at least one non-NA (`filter_at`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(.[order(is.na(.))])) %>% 
   filter_at(vars(var1:var3), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
#  id    var1  var2  var3 
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 A     100   100   200  
#2 A     200   400   700  
#3 A     300   500   800  
#4 A     <NA>  600   <NA> 
#5 B     100   400   500  
#6 B     200   <NA>  500  
#7 B     300   <NA>  600
```

---

Ordering a vector/column based on logical indexing is simple.

```
v1 <- c(1:3, NA, 5, NA, 7)
order(is.na(v1)) #gives the index of order
#[1] 1 2 3 5 7 4 6
```

use that index to change the order of values

```
v1[order(is.na(v1))]
#[1]  1  2  3  5  7 NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful answer. Could you please explain this part `   `mutate_all(funs(.[order(is.na(.))])) %>%` in this answer

Comment: @amrrs Updated the answer.  Hopefully, it helps

Comment: This was perfect thanks but now gives a warning because `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0. Can anyone suggest the new way this should be written? 



```

Warning message:   

`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.  Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:   

# Simple named list: list(mean = mean, median = median).   

# Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: tibble::lst(mean, median).   

# Using lambdas list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE)).   

Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.   

```

Answer (score 0):

here is a base solution, if your real case doesn't feature factors you can skip the first and last lines :

```
df[] <- lapply(df,as.character)
. <- lapply(split(df,df$id),lapply, na.omit)
. <- lapply(., function(x) lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x[-1]))))
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(., do.call, what = data.frame))
df[] <- lapply(df, factor)

#     id var1 var2 var3
# A.1  A  100  100  200
# A.2  A  200  400  700
# A.3  A  300  500  800
# A.4  A <NA>  600 <NA>
# B.1  B  100  400  500
# B.2  B  200 <NA>  500
# B.3  B  300 <NA>  600
```